# psplash not shown during boottime although its callable from console

Tags: yocto

Im building a yocto image for an imx6q with qt. Everything now works as expected. The only remaining issue is the missing splashscreen at boottime.

- psplash seems to be installed, as i can start it from console
- Its not the wrong framebuffer
- The psplash.sh is in /etc/init.d

Any thougts or known issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you use systemd than sysvinit maybe this is the problem, i've tried use psplash with systemd once and it did't work for me. Didn't find out why I haven't time for that.